# Law of large numbers, variant

Tags: probability

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with zero mean and finite variance. I'm trying to find conditions on $\alpha$ that would guarantee the convergence in probability to $0$ of $\frac{|X_1+...+X_n|}{n^\alpha}$. So far I have $P(\frac{|X_1+...+X_n|}{n^\alpha}<z)=1-P(\frac{|X_1+...+X_n|}{n^\alpha}\geq z)\geq 1-\frac{E(|X_1+...+X_n|^2)}{n^{2\alpha}}\geq 1-\frac{\alpha}{n^{2\alpha-1}}$. Hence if $\alpha>1/2$we have convergence in probability. Now I can't find a way to prove non convergence when $\alpha<1/2$, i.e. prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\frac{|X_1+...+X_n|}{n^\alpha}<z)=0$ when $\alpha<1/2$. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove this! If $X_n=0$ for all $n$ then all the conditions are satisfied and the ratio converges to $0$ even for $\alpha <\frac 1 2$. In general you cannot hope to find a necessary and sufficient condition in terms of $\alpha$.